# Project deployment stuck at Registering the application to run from layout

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have created a Windows Store 8.1 app and I'm trying to deploy on the local machine. The project builds correctly, but it is not deployed. Visual Studio 2013 looks like it is working but on the Output window I see following lines, and the deployments gets stuck there:

```
1>Creating a new clean layout...
1>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
1>Registering the application to run from layout...
```

It doesn't show any errors.

I have tried by rebuilding the project and restarting VS, but I'm still not able to deploy the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try renewing your developer's license. Also, restarting the computer.

Comment: Restarting the computer after renewing the license solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Renew your developer's license, then restart the computer.

## Steps

1. Open any Windows Store apps project and go to the "Project" menu.
2. Select Store > "Acquire Developer License..."
3. In the Window, click "I Agree" (after reading all of the terms, conditions, and privacy statement, right?)
4. Sign in with your developer account.
5. If everything works, your developer license should be renewed.
6. Restart your computer.

Comment: Wow... thanks for this solution! Worked for me too. It's really impossible to know how to fix things when it gives you no error at all.

Comment: Can you please add instructions on how to do that?

Comment: @tmr232 As you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10, VS 2013, VS 2015:
1.) Restart your computer
2.) check that under settings/update&security/for developer/'Developer mode' is enabled
3.) open elevated powershell (as administrator)
4.) enter: Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense
5.) enter: shutdown /r /t 0 (this will reboot your computer) and wait
6.) start VS, create a new project, built and run on local machine

also you might want to take a look at this link at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974578.aspx)